# BASH - Getting the last modified date from file without using stat

Tags: bash, unix, timestamp, sunos

I am trying to get a time stamp and convert it to the format - `YYYYMMDD`. I don't know how to get the date without using stat and I can't install stat because it is a company server. I have looked around but it seems everyone would use stat.

Comment: "I have a bolt I need loosened, but I lost my wrench and vice grips." `stat` or a program that uses the `stat()` call are pretty much your options. Did you try the output from `ls -l` or similar and parse it yourself?

Comment: I would try `find test.file -printf "%t\n"` - however I guess that this will also need `stat` in the back. That's why I don't post it as an answer. If `find` works, you can change the format as well. Just `man find` and search for `printf`.

Comment: @KarstenS [SunOS find](http://www.manpages.info/sunos/find.1.html) supports `-printf`. This is a good solution.

Comment: getting result find: bad option -printf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use GNU `stat`, maybe you can sneak under the radar and use Perl's stat :-)

```
perl -MPOSIX -e 'print POSIX::strftime "%Y%m%d\n", localtime((stat $ARGV[0])[9])' yourfile
```

Result:

```
20140303
```

Many thanks to Glenn Jackman (see Comments below) for magnificently filling the role of "clever person" and showing me where I was going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: LOL! @mpapec can only be summoned with `perl` tag though!!

Comment: You need to convert the epoch time from stat into the array required by strftime: `perl -MPOSIX -e 'print POSIX::strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime((stat $ARGV[0])[9])'`

Comment: @jaypal :-) You make him sound like an oracle - or dragon, maybe ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 ls -l --time-style="+%Y%m%d" filename
```

Comment: getting an illegal option. I might just need parse the ls -l filename return seperate

Answer (score 0):

Expanding from Amit's answer to just return the timestamp

```
ls -l --time-style="+%Y%m%d" ./filename |cut -d " " -f 6
```